# TFS 2015 builds on Windows 2008 server machine , configure build to invoke on another PC

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015, iar

We have TFS 2015 build machine ( for .Net application) on windows 2008 server. Also we are using embedded SW ( IAR Embedded Workbench ) tool, which  does not support Windows Server versions so if we want to incorporate embedded SW to the build.

is it possible to configure the build to invoke the embedded SW build on another PC (for ex. Windows7 )?

Comment: Are you using XAML build or vNext build?

Comment: using vNext build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommend to use [Windows Build Agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/agents/windows) to run [vNext build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/overview). The easiest way is to deploy the Windows Build Agent on the embedded SW machine directly, then the build will run on this machine.

Or you can add a [PowerShell on Target Machines](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/PowerShellOnTargetMachines) task to run PowerShell script on the embedded SW machine.

Comment: powershell on target machines looks fine solutions for me now. Since i am beginner, i don't understand how windows build agent on target machine ( embedded SW machine )   and build agent on server machine works in my case.  if you can explain bit more ? , a i really appreciate it , or any links that expalin ?

Comment: If you are going to use powershell on target machines task, then you don't need to deploy a new build agent, just add tasks in your build definition: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/build